# Single Speechmarks not added to numbers

Tags: groovy

I have the below Code which works, except for if there is a number in the text field so a single speech mark does not get added around say 1 but would be around one.

As an aside I don't want speechmarks on the first column (the ID value)

```
SEP = ", "
QUOTE     = "\'"
NEWLINE   = System.getProperty("line.separator")

KEYWORDS_LOWERCASE = com.intellij.database.util.DbSqlUtil.areKeywordsLowerCase(PROJECT)
KW_INSERT_INTO = KEYWORDS_LOWERCASE ? "insert into " : "INSERT INTO "
KW_VALUES = KEYWORDS_LOWERCASE ? ") values (" : ") VALUES ("
KW_NULL = KEYWORDS_LOWERCASE ? "null" : "NULL"

def record(columns, dataRow) {
    OUT.append(KW_INSERT_INTO)
    if (TABLE == null) OUT.append("MY_TABLE")
    else OUT.append(TABLE.getParent().getName()).append(".").append(TABLE.getName())
    OUT.append(" (")

    columns.eachWithIndex { column, idx ->
        OUT.append(column.name()).append(idx != columns.size() - 1 ? SEP : "")
    }

    OUT.append(KW_VALUES)
    columns.eachWithIndex { column, idx ->
        def value = dataRow.value(column)

        def stringValue = value != null ? FORMATTER.format(dataRow, column) : KW_NULL
        if (DIALECT.getDbms().isMysql())
         stringValue = stringValue.replace("\\", "\\\\")

        OUT.append(skipQuote ? "": QUOTE).append(stringValue.replace(QUOTE, QUOTE + QUOTE))
           .append(skipQuote ? "": QUOTE).append(idx != columns.size() - 1 ? SEP : "")
    }
    OUT.append(");").append(NEWLINE)
}

ROWS.each { row -> record(COLUMNS, row) }
```

Comment: you should be using https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html and not re-invent the wheel of putting a query togegher over and over again

Comment: The above is what comes with PHPStorm. Thanks for the link, any specific bit if you know it? This is a one off extraction.

Comment: I didn't really get it. Is this the code you can change?

Comment: Sorry. The code shown is from PHPStorm (from Jetbrains). It can be changed, I'm just not sure why/how the code picks up a field has only numbers in, when it's 'really' text.

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: What I need is for everything is a text column/field to have a ' around it i.e. '1' and 'text'. What currently happens, in the same field is text in the text field is numerical then their is no single speech mark.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what and why you are trying to achieve, but I would write down something like that in idiomatic groovy:

```
LinkedHashMap.metaClass.value = { delegate.get it } // mock value()
TABLE = [ parent:[ name:'OTHER_TABLE' ] ] // fake TABLE

KEYWORDS_LOWERCASE = true // false

KW_INSERT_INTO = 'INSERT INTO'
KW_VALUES = 'VALUES'
if( KEYWORDS_LOWERCASE ){
  KW_INSERT_INTO = KW_INSERT_INTO.toLowerCase()
  KW_VALUES = KW_VALUES.toLowerCase()
}

COLUMNS = [ 'a', 'nullllll', 'c', 'numberString' ]

String record(columns, dataRow) {
  List values = columns.collect{
    def v = dataRow.value it
    switch( v ){
      case Number:
      case ~/\d+/: return v
      case String: return "'$v'"
      default: return 'null'
    }
  }
  "$KW_INSERT_INTO ${TABLE?.parent?.name ?: 'MY_TABLE'} (${columns.join( ', ' )}) $KW_VALUES (${values.join( ', ' )});\n"
}

String res = record( COLUMNS, [ a:'aa', c:42, numberString:'84' ] )
assert res == "insert into OTHER_TABLE (a, nullllll, c, numberString) values ('aa', null, 42, 84);\n"
```

In `switch` statement the values are getting formatted.

You can try out yourself at https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5151418931478528